# Use data.table to change columns' values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset `dft` consisting of variables `name`, `weight`, `height` like the following

```
name <- c("Bob","Mary","Jane","Kim")
weight <- c(60,65,45,55)
height <- c(170,165,140,135)
dft <- data.table(name,weight,height,)
```

Now for `Bob`, I want to add 10 to its weight and 12 to its height. I tried this:

```
dft[, c("weight","height") := lapply( .SD,  function(x){  
                             if (x == c(60,170) ) {
                                x = c(70,182)
                             }
                                  }), .SDcols = grep("eight$",names(dft)) ]
```

but it's not working. Warnings and errors have repeatedly appeared. I wish to use `lapply` to do it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Would this work for you? It's a little unclear to me why you want to use `lapply`. `dft[name=="Bob", c("weight", "height") := .(weight + 10, height+12)]`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `fifelse` with `Map` (assuming that we are matching the values)

```
library(data.table)
dft[, c("weight","height") := Map(function(x, y) 
    fifelse(x %in% c(60, 170), x + y, x), .SD, c(10, 12)),
      .SDcols =  patterns('eight$')][]
```

-output

```
#    name weight height
#1:  Bob     70    182
#2: Mary     65    165
#3: Jane     45    140
#4:  Kim     55    135
```

---

Or if it is based on the value of 'name'

```
dft[name == 'Bob', c('weight', 'height') :=
       .SD + list(10, 12), .SDcols = patterns("eight$")]
```

#### data

```
dft <- data.table(name,weight,height)
```